# What was the name of the anthology with a crystal bell that brings people to life and a man who gains a "knack" for counterfeiting?

Tags: story-identification, horror

When I asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55159/short-story-about-a-man-donating-a-rare-blood-type-who-learns-that-the-donation), I mistakenly conflated two other stories into the collection.

> Based on eliminating the anthologies that I did browse at home, it might have been in a volume that included two other stories. One involved a crystal bell that could bring people back to the life in exchange for the loss of another's life (initially, the bell didn't work, but someone realized that they had the clapper on their necklace) which ended with someone falling on the bell and having a shard pierce their heart. The other about a man who somehow bought two "knacks", in his case the ability to compose rhymes at any time (and, in fact, he couldn't stop rhyming) and the ability to "make money" which translated to him doodling out perfectly detailed dollar bills whenever his thoughts drifted. Faced with legal problems from accidentally counterfeiting, and his wife becoming increasingly annoyed at the rhyming, he somehow exchanged the gift of "making money" for the gift of silence, and started working for a greeting card company. I do believe those two stories were in the same anthology, but I am not 100% certain that it was with the same one as the vampire and the blood donor.

I have since found that I wind up searching for these stories periodically, so I'm posting a self-answer for the stories in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story about the crystal bell is "[The Rose-Crystal Bell](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?665333)" by Robert Arthur. Summary from [here](http://www.scaryforkids.com/hidden-gems/):

> A woman finds a bell in an antique shop and the owner of the shop tells her it is cursed. When the bell is rung, it can bring a dead person back to life, but someone else must die in their place. Her husband is a doctor and they have a son together. In the middle of the night, the woman receives the terrible news that her her son has been killed in a horrible car accident. She rushes down to the hospital and rings the bell. Her son comes out and greets her, telling her that there was some kind of misunderstanding because he had been in a different car and wasn’t killed in the accident. She drops the bell in shock and it shatters into pieces, but according to the legend about the bell, someone else still needs to die.

The story about the man with a knack for counterfeiting is "[Mr. Milton's Gift](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?187678)", also by Robert Arthur. Summary from [here](https://www.etsy.com/in-en/listing/113779944/ghosts-and-more-ghosts-by-robert-arthur):

> Homer's troubles began when he walked into the strangest little gift shop he'd ever seen. All he had wanted was a gift for his wife, but the odd little proprietor with the glowing yellow eyes had sold him quite a different sort of gift...the gift of verse. Now, no matter what Homer said, it came out in rhyme and he couldn't stop it!

I read them both in a collection named *[Ghosts and More Ghosts](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12262271-ghosts-and-more-ghosts)* which contained the following stories, all by Robert Arthur:

[image: Book cover]

- "Footsteps Invisible" - A tomb-robber confides in a blind newspaper seller that he is being pursued by a vengeful guardian who can only be perceived by its footsteps.
- "Mr. Milton's Gift" - Homer Milton steps into a strange gift shop and gains the "gift to make money" and "the gift of verse", and it proceeds to make his life a hell.
- "The Rose Crystal Bell" - A woman finds the eponymous rose-crystal bell and learns that, when rung, it can bring a dead person back to life, but another will die in their place.
- "Don't Be a Goose" - A meek historian successfully performs mental time travel to Rome, but winds up in the body of a goose.
- "Obstinate Uncle Otis" - Ever since he was struck by lightning, Uncle Otis has been able to make things cease to exist by disbelieving in them.
- "Do You Believe in Ghosts?" - A story-teller for a "true life" horror show accidentally taps into a power greater than himself and must confront true horror.
- "The Stamps for El Dorado" - A set of stamps are found that transport the posted object to a magical island.
- "The Wonderful Day" - A boy's fever-driven wish on a unicorn horn causes numerous figures of speech to come to life in his town.
- "Mr. Dexter's Dragon" - A cursed book contains an illustration of a dragon which seems to get fatter with every owner who turns up missing.
- "Hank Garvey's Daytime Ghost" - Hank Garvey is a peculiar man who works at night and sleeps during the day. A young boy, Johnny, sets out to find out why, and learns that Hank is haunted by the ghost of his ever-contrary grandfather, who appears as an inky shade only visible in daylight.

Comment: The book was also suggested at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31387/searching-for-a-book-of-short-stories-blind-man-hears-a-monster-shuffle-shuff/125806#125806, but is not the accepted answer.

Comment: Some of the stories have also shown up, but not this collection.

Comment: "Mr. Dexter's Dragon" at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181334/juvenile-youth-fantasy-short-story-about-a-book-with-a-dragon-that-emerges-to-ea

Comment: "The Stamps for El Dorado" at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141153/possibly-a-kids-book-about-magic-stamps-from-el-dorado

Comment: "Obstinate Uncle Otis" at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204685/which-was-the-first-story-featuring-a-psychic-being-unable-to-control-their-own/204702#204702